# In rethinkdb data explorer, how to add dataTable plugins to get automatic detection of numeric columns?

Tags: jquery, datatable, whitelist, rethinkdb

In rethinkdb administive data explorer window, DataTable is provided but it is not displaying table data in dataTable format. So ihave modified code such that it will show table view as Data Table.  When i am trying to add new "js" plugin file, it is giving "info: Someone asked for the nonwhitelisted file "/js/num-html.js".  If this should be accessible, add it to the whitelist." message in info. Will it be possible to add js files to whitelist? If possible, what is the procedure to add files to whitelist?

Comment: It is not possible to add files to the whitelist without recompiling RethinkDB from scratch.

Comment: Please open an issue in http://github.com/rethinkdb/issues, we might be able to change the current behaviour. Meanwhile you can append your custom js code to one of the existing js files in the web assets directory.

Answer (score 1):

RethinkDB has a built-in HTTP server that serves the web UI -- but the only files that can be served have to be whitelisted.

You'll need to [recompile the server from source](http://rethinkdb.com/docs/build/) so it can serve your own JavaScript files ([here's the script](https://github.com/rethinkdb/rethinkdb/blob/next/scripts/compile-web-assets.py) that generates the whitelist at build time). The build script whitelists all files located in the `/admin` directory in RethinkDB' source tree (which includes the source for the web UI), which is where you can add your custom code.

Alternatively, you can append your JavaScript snippets to the end of an existing file being served by the web UI (as AtnNn suggested).

Comment: If you've built useful additions to the web UI, consider [opening a pull request](https://github.com/rethinkdb/rethinkdb/pulls) so we can add those changes to RethinkDB as well.